# Filter Web Parts in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I can't find an option to activate Filter Web Parts in SharePoint 2013 like Content query filter web parts etc. They are not visible in Web Parts gallery!

Is there an option to activate them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ensure that Enterprise feature (Site collection level) is activated

[image]